# poles of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

What are the poles of a polynomial? Are they the same as the roots?

Comment: Do you know what a pole is?

Comment: A pole of a complex function $f(z)$ at $z_0$ is, roughly, an isolated singularity in whose neighborhood the Laurent series of the function has only a finite number of negative powers of $(z-z_0)$.  

This immediately suggests that your polynomial cannot have a pole in the (finite) complex plane because it can be expanded using a Taylor series (no negative powers) about any point.

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest answer possible for your question:

There are no poles of a polynomial.

Comment: Perhaps the situation that prompted this question refers to a pole at infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Brief answer: a pole refers to the location of a special type of discontinuity, in fact a special sort of singularity.  Polynomials on the real line or complex plane are continuous, and thus do not have any poles in the real or complex numbers.

However we have a very similar object in the complex case called a pole at infinity.  Essentially a function $f(z)$ has a pole at infinity if $f(1/z)$ has a pole at $0$.  Any nonconstant polynomial has a pole at infinity.

Depending on your experience, the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis) might help you or be a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

A (nonconstant) polynomial may be considered to have a pole at infinity.